# Endless scroll RecyclerView gives a random item twice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on getting a RecyclerView to display data from a big ArrayList of gardening tips. The RecyclerView row is full screen. When user scrolls to the end of the list, a random item should be pulled.

I have it half-working. But the problem is `existingTipsList.add(newRandomTip) (and the print statement below it)` is being called every other swipe, which is causing the data to duplicate twice.

**Here is my progress:**

**Adapter**

```
class GardeningTipAdapter(val dataSource:ArrayList<GardeningTipsModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GardeningTipAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.gardening_tips_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSource.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val text = dataSource[position].gardeningTipFull
        holder.label.text = text
    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val label: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gardening_tips_row)
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
object GardeningTipsData {

    fun allGardeningTips() : ArrayList<TipsModel>{
        return arrayListOf(

            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 1"),
            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 2"),
            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 3"),
            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 4"),
            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 5"),
            TipsModel("Gardening Tip 6"),

            )
    }

    fun getRandomTip(currentTips: ArrayList<TipsModel>): ArrayList<TipsModel> {
        val allTipsList = allGardeningTips()
        val randomIndex = (0 until allTipsList.size).random()
        val randomTip = allTipsList[randomIndex]

        currentTips.add(randomTip)

        return currentTips
    }

}
```

**Scroll listener**

```
private val existingTipsList = ArrayList<TipsModel>()

    // Initial setup with a single random tip
    existingTipsList.add(GardeningTipsData.getRandomTip(existingTipsList).last())
    binding.tipRecyclerView.adapter = GardeningTipAdapter(existingTipsList)

    var loading = true
    var pastVisiblesItems: Int = 0
    var visibleItemCount: Int = 0
    var totalItemCount: Int = 0

    binding.tipRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (dy > 0) { // check for scroll down
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.childCount
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

                if (loading) {
                    if (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems >= totalItemCount && !lastItemAdded) {
                        loading = false

                        // Get a new random item and append it to the list
                        val newRandomTip = GardeningTipsData.getRandomTip(existingTipsList).last()
                        existingTipsList.add(newRandomTip)
                        println("ADDED NEW!")

                        // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
                        binding.tipRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemInserted(existingTipsList.size - 1)

                        lastItemAdded = true
                        loading = true
                    } else {
                        lastItemAdded = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

With this setup, this is what you see when you scroll through the RecyclerView:

```
Gardening Tip 5
Gardening Tip 5
Gardening Tip 1
Gardening Tip 1
Gardening Tip 4
Gardening Tip 4
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 1
Gardening Tip 1
```

The objective is to display the data at random, like the following:

```
Gardening Tip 5
Gardening Tip 4
Gardening Tip 1
Gardening Tip 3
Gardening Tip 6
Gardening Tip 1
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 3
Gardening Tip 4
Gardening Tip 5
Gardening Tip 2
Gardening Tip 5
```

**I believe the issue is every time a new item gets appended to the arrayList, it gets added twice, which is causing the duplication. How can I adjust this so that the data displays at random and `existingTipsList.add(newRandomTip)` gets called when the user hits the last item?**

Answer (score 1):

You are adding to the `existingTipsList` list that you send as a parameter, both with `currentTips.add(randomTip)` in `getRandomTip` function and with `existingTipsList.add(newRandomTip)` line. Notice that you are adding to the same list reference? Please try the solution below.

```
fun getRandomTip(currentTips: ArrayList<TipsModel>): ArrayList<TipsModel> {
    val allTipsList = allGardeningTips()
    val randomIndex = (0 until allTipsList.size).random()
    val randomTip = allTipsList[randomIndex]
    
    val tips = arrayListOf<TipsModel>()
    tips.addAll(currentTips)
    tips.add(randomTip)

    return tips
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be loading a new tip at all once scrolled. The dataset is staying at 1 item.